# 2 tags on GTM send duplicate data or not?

Tags: duplicates, google-tag-manager, google-ads-data-hub

I have one concern. I have one conversion on Google Ads. But I have 2 tags on Google Tag Manager with the same conversion ID and conversion label. Each tag "form submission" uses a different trigger and they are all correct. The reason why I have 2 tags is just a mistake and I have realised it quite late.
My concern is that if a user completes a conversion and both tags fired at the same time, will data send duplicate to the conversion action on Google ads? Or just send one only?

Thank you for your help.

I hope I can know will data be sent duplicate or just one time.

Answer (score 1):

Open your network tab, clear it, open your console in the drawer. In the console, trigger your pixel, find the corresponding network hit. Trigger it again. Here, this is some very simple testing:

[image]

See how I call it three times, but it only fires once in the network? If I change the conversion id, it will fire again, but the gtag library is smart enough to ignore repeated conversions when it detects them, anticipating poor implementations on the client side.

Moreover, it is possible that the ad platform does even more deduplications removing repeated conversions on the user-level.

In conclusion: you have nothing to worry about, but also, fix your tracking. It's rarely okay to publish sloppy work to prod.

Comment: Thanks so much Bnazaruk, though I may take sometimes to digest due to the limitation of IT knowledge, I truly appreciate your valuable response.